# Why do I see login requests for various ports although the router and the firewall only permit port 22?

Tags: ssh, firewall, ufw, port-forwarding

I want to login into the Desktop of my Ubuntu 18.04 machine remotely from the internet.

I therefore enabled port forwarding for port 22 in my (fritz.box) router.

Additionally I activated the firewall and allowed only requests to port 22 from outside:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Nevertheless I can see the following log entries in my `/var/log/auth.log` file (I changed my computer name and the ip addresses from the originators of the requests).

**My question is: why do I see these entries for ports different than 22?**

Remark:
Presently, I allow login via password (but I will disable this with the next try I want to make by allowing only logins via the private/public key pattern).

```
Dec 21 06:56:05 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26654]: Disconnected from invalid user user IP_ADDRESS_1_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 51904 [preauth]
Dec 21 06:56:50 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26656]: Invalid user user from IP_ADDRESS_1_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 53030
Dec 21 06:56:50 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26656]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Dec 21 06:56:50 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26656]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_1_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY
Dec 21 06:56:51 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26656]: Failed password for invalid user user from IP_ADDRESS_1_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 53030 ssh2
Dec 21 06:56:52 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26656]: Received disconnect from IP_ADDRESS_1_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 53030:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Dec 21 06:56:52 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26656]: Disconnected from invalid user user IP_ADDRESS_1_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 53030 [preauth]
Dec 21 07:09:01 this-is-my-computer-name CRON[26678]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 21 07:09:01 this-is-my-computer-name CRON[26678]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 21 07:17:01 this-is-my-computer-name CRON[26732]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 21 07:17:01 this-is-my-computer-name CRON[26732]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 21 07:19:37 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26736]: Did not receive identification string from IP_ADDRESS_2_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 57230
Dec 21 07:20:42 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26738]: Invalid user user from IP_ADDRESS_2_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 39416
Dec 21 07:20:42 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26738]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Dec 21 07:20:42 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26738]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_2_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY
Dec 21 07:20:45 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26738]: Failed password for invalid user user from IP_ADDRESS_2_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 39416 ssh2
Dec 21 07:20:45 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26738]: Received disconnect from IP_ADDRESS_2_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 39416:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Dec 21 07:20:45 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26738]: Disconnected from invalid user user IP_ADDRESS_2_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 39416 [preauth]
Dec 21 07:21:37 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26741]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY  user=root
Dec 21 07:21:39 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26741]: Failed password for root from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 20851 ssh2
Dec 21 07:21:44 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26741]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 20851 ssh2]
Dec 21 07:21:45 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26741]: Received disconnect from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 20851:11:  [preauth]
Dec 21 07:21:45 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26741]: Disconnected from authenticating user root IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 20851 [preauth]
Dec 21 07:21:45 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26741]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY  user=root
Dec 21 07:21:47 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26743]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY  user=root
Dec 21 07:21:49 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26743]: Failed password for root from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 37120 ssh2
Dec 21 07:21:54 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26743]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 37120 ssh2]
Dec 21 07:21:54 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26743]: Received disconnect from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 37120:11:  [preauth]
Dec 21 07:21:54 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26743]: Disconnected from authenticating user root IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 37120 [preauth]
Dec 21 07:21:54 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26743]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY  user=root
Dec 21 07:21:57 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26745]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY  user=root
Dec 21 07:21:58 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26745]: Failed password for root from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 42983 ssh2
Dec 21 07:22:03 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26745]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 42983 ssh2]
Dec 21 07:22:03 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26745]: Received disconnect from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 42983:11:  [preauth]
Dec 21 07:22:03 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26745]: Disconnected from authenticating user root IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 42983 [preauth]
Dec 21 07:22:03 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26745]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY  user=root
Dec 21 07:22:05 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26747]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY  user=root
Dec 21 07:22:08 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26747]: Failed password for root from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 43076 ssh2
Dec 21 07:22:13 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26747]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 43076 ssh2]
Dec 21 07:22:13 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26747]: Received disconnect from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 43076:11:  [preauth]
Dec 21 07:22:13 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26747]: Disconnected from authenticating user root IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 43076 [preauth]
Dec 21 07:22:13 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26747]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY  user=root
Dec 21 07:22:15 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26749]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY  user=root
Dec 21 07:22:18 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26749]: Failed password for root from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 49861 ssh2
Dec 21 07:22:22 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26749]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 49861 ssh2]
Dec 21 07:22:23 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26749]: Received disconnect from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 49861:11:  [preauth]
Dec 21 07:22:23 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26749]: Disconnected from authenticating user root IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 49861 [preauth]
Dec 21 07:22:23 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26749]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY  user=root
Dec 21 07:22:25 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26751]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY  user=root
Dec 21 07:22:27 this-is-my-computer-name sshd[26751]: Failed password for root from IP_ADDRESS_3_IN_A_FOREIGN_COUNTRY port 53988 ssh2
```

Comment: Every nanosecond you're connected to the Internet, the Internet is connected to you. There are bad people on the Internet. Investigate `fail2ban`.

Comment: The ports listed are source ports. The destination port was 22 and so UFW allows the packets.